# how to write SQL Statement - hibernate/persistence query exception - could not resolve property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, persistence, hql

I'm new to Hibernate and SQL, so I might did something wrong and won't see it - even after spending the second day now on it:

in my PostgreSQL DB, I have two tables:

```
PieChartResult
+---------+---------+--------------+-------+----------+----------+----------------+
| id      | answer  | approvalrate | input | worktime | workerid | piecharthit_id |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------+----------+----------+----------------+


PieChartHit
+---------+-----------+
| id      | truevalue |
+---------+-----------+
```

Then I write in pgAdmin following SQL statement, which works perfectly fine:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT input, answer FROM piecharthit INNER JOIN piechartresult ON piecharthit.id=piechartresult_piecharthit_id;
```

I get a result table where I see all the collected answers for each input.

When I'm trying to write the same statement in java

```
Query q = em.createQuery(SELECT DISTINCT a FROM PieChartHit a INNER JOIN a.PiechartResult b WHERE a.id=b.piecharthit_id")
```

I just get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: PieChartResult of: PieChartHit [SELECT DISTINCT a FROM PieChartHit a INNER JOIN a.PieChartResult b WHERE a.id=b.piecharthit_id]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1364)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:37)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: PieChartResult of: PieChartHit [SELECT DISTINCT a FROM PieChartHit a INNER JOIN a.PieChartResult b WHERE a.id=b.piecharthit_id]
```

the both classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PieChartResult")
public class PieChartResult {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String workerID;
private String approvalRate;
private String input;
private double answer;

@ManyToOne
private PieChartHit piecharthit;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PieChartHIT")
public class PieChartHit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private double trueValue;
```

would someone please guide this lost soul? :(

Comment: I think in my current project I did the same thing let me know if you need help. Let me know this first are you able to run simple `SELECT * ` queries then think about complex queries.Also in your code there is no reference of PieChartResult in PieChartHit Basically 

`private List<PieChartResult> pieChartResult;` has to be part of your code in entity of `PieChartHit`

I think this VIDEO would be helpful : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAi8bY-H_ek&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=17&feature=plpp_video

Comment: Hi. Yes, 'SELECT *' statements works fine. Do you know how I could print out all results from my Query 'q'?

Comment: watch the video use mappedBy method and then try and insert records using session.save. I think I will create a new answer and will tell you the impl.

please vote for my answer if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should write HQL, not SQL.  This means you use the class/field names instead of the table/column names.  Note that the exception says "could not resolve **property**".

Also, you are missing quotes around the hql string in your query line.

Edit, based on your code, you are selecting from `PieChartHit` on its reference to `PieChartResult`, but it doesn't look like the relationship is bi directional.  Also

`@Table(name="PieChartHIT")`

looks like you have a capitalization issue.

Comment: I second this. The basic idea of using Hibernate is to not write complex join queries on our own.

Answer (score 0):

This is in continuation with the original comment 
It shows how to grab the result into a list.. 
I think you need to change your Class Definition of `PieChartResult` and `PieChartHit` in order for the hibernate to work.

```
String hql = "from CrawlerElement e where request.id = :requestId";
Query q = getSession().createQuery(sql); //getSession is not the actual method.
q.setParameter("requestId", id);
elements = q.list(); //elements is a List<CrawlerElement> where CrawlerElement which is actual @Entity
return elements;
```

Comment: thanks for the example. But  why do you think I should change my Class Definitions?

Comment: It is difficult to explain by typing but I will try: why dont you watch video which I mentioned it explains your problem ditto. check it out. If you want to google : Many to one and one to many hibernate example using annotations this link might be really helpful [hibernate](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/)